# Create a widget using QStackedLayout

Tags: qt, layout, widget

Hi everyone I'm pretty new to programming with Qt and I would like to create a widget using a `QStackedLayout`. I already designed some widgets with Qt Creator, added them to the `QStackedLayout` and set it to the main widget. But now I would like to change the widgets using buttons inside the added widgets using the [`setCurrentIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html#public-slots) method. Now I have to use the `connect` function but in the main widget class I can't access components from the other widgets to connect them. So how can I do this?

```
#include "mainwindowwidget.h"
#include "ui_mainwindowwidget.h"


MainWindowWidget::MainWindowWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindowWidget)
{


    qApp->setStyleSheet("MainWindowWidget {background-color : red}");

    //initializing widgets
    this->mainWidget_ = new MainWidget;
    this->createGameWidget_ = new CreateGameWidget;
    this->widgets_ = new QStackedLayout;


    //adding widgets to QstackedLayout
    this->widgets_->addWidget(this->mainWidget_);
    this->widgets_->addWidget(this->createGameWidget_);

    this->setLayout(this->widgets_);
    this->showFullScreen();
    // I would like to connect the qstackedlayout
    // = widgets_ with a button placed in mainwidget_
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindowWidget::~MainWindowWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Qt Assistance

```
The QStackedLayout class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time.
```

So passing index is a key thing to identify the widget need to be displayed on StackedLayout at a particular point of time. Suppose your signal name is  "activated(int)" declared in both mainWidget_ and createGameWidget_

So you need to connect like this

> ```
> //MainWindowWidget class.
> connect(MainWidget, SIGNAL(activated(int)), widgets_ , SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
> connect(createGameWidget_, SIGNAL(activated(int)), widgets_ , SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
> ```

```
   //In MainWidget class you need to emit signal
    MainWidget::ChangeLayout()
    {
        emit activated(1); //createGameWidget_will be displayed
    }

   //In createGameWidget_class you need to emit signal
    createGameWidget_::ChangeLayout()
    {
        emit activated(0); //MainWidget will be displayed
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here. If your button is a public member of `MainWidget`, then you can simply connect the button's `clicked()` signal to your slot in `MainWindow`.

```
//mainwindow.h
...
public slots:
   void buttonClicked();
```

```
//mainwindow.cpp
...
   connect(mainWidget_->button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));
...
void buttonClicked()
{
   //do what you want to do here...
}
```

Another option is to create a custom signal in your `MainWidget` class. Then connect your button's `clicked()` signal to this custom signal:

```
//mainwidget.h
...
signals:
   void buttonClickedSignal();
```

```
//mainwidget.cpp
   connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(buttonClickedSignal()));
```

Then connect your `buttonClickedSignal()` signal to a slot in your `MainWindow`:

```
//mainwindow.cpp
   connect(mainWidget_, SIGNAL(buttonClickedSignal()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));
```

A third option would be to add a function to your `MainWidget` class, that returns a pointer to your button. Then call this function in your `MainWindow` class, and use that pointer to connect your button to a slot.

```
//mainwidget.h
...
public:
   QPushButton* getButton();
...
```

```
//mainwdiget.cpp
...
QPushButton* getButton()
{
   return button;
}
...
```

```
//mainwindow.cpp
...
   QPushButton *button = mainWidget_->getButton();
   connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked()));
```